# Deployment to Heroku Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, deployment

I'm deploying an Angular 6 application created with the angular-cli to Heroku. The build completes successfully, however, when I go to the deployed application, I get a blank page.

After running the Heroku logs, it appears the error/crash happens upon starting up the node server instance. "Cannot find module '/app/server/js". The server.js file lives under the src directory so I don't know why this is happening.

from the logs:
[image]

Here is the package.json, I removed the node and npm engines to run the default versions from the heroku build:

```
{
  "name": "blog-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.8.1-next",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

And the server.js:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();

app.use(static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

File tree:

[image]

Any idea on what the problem could be?

EDIT: I added a Procfile at src/Procfile:

```
web: node src/server.js
```

After adding this file, the app still crashes with the following output in the Heroku logs:

[image]

Comment: Post your `Procfile`

Comment: You put node server in angular src path? I can't see the image...

Comment: yes, the server.js path is 'src/server.js'

Comment: I'm new to Heroku, where can I find the Procfile to share @FranciscoMateo

Comment: how is your Procfile ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a Procfile with following content

```
web: node src/server.js
```

The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named Procfile exactly. For example, Procfile.txt is not valid.

The Procfile must live in your app’s root directory. It does not function if placed anywhere else.

Heroku app dynos executes the commands of Procfile

Read more about Procfile here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: I added this file (see edit above), but still the app crashes :(

Comment: @Kode_12 Don't add Procfile inside src folder . Place it parallel to package.json(root folder)

Comment: jesus I spend 2 hours trying to find the error. it was the '.txt' that caused the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Create Procfile in main folder and add:

```
web: node src/<you-app-name>.js
```

Check the below image for where to put Procfile:

[image: visit link to view where to put Procfile]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue during deployment of my MERN stack web application.So when I checked my package.json in scripts the name of the file was different to index.js and the heroku was trying to find app.js .So change the name in the start to the file name in your root directory.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node index.js",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --force --prefix Client && npm run build --prefix Client"
},
```