# Application error on heroku when trying to submit my proyect

Tags: javascript, heroku, npm

Hosted my app on Heroku, everything was going well according to a tutorial on YT but then you enter the link it says App error. I don't know what could be the problem according to the logs that appear as follows:

### [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJyQ1.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9fQ1.png)

**EDIT: Here are the files.**
Also I forgot to mention I am new to heroku and hosting in general

### [package&files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAlJm.png)

### [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIpoF.png)

### [index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8yI4.png)

when trying to start the server again it shows this about the Procfile
remote: ~Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
remote: ~Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.

Comment: From the logs, it seems like it's not possible to find the module `app\app`. To help you, please share your configuration and code, so we can help you spot the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deployment to Heroku Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571078/deployment-to-heroku-error-cannot-find-module-app-server-js)

Comment: I don't have idea of where I can find the /app/app module myself