# How to fix Heroku Deploy Error - Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'

Tags: javascript, heroku

Any assistance with the below would be highly appreciated. I've received a series of errors, most of which I was able to resolve, but one persists:

> Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'

I was able to fix similar errors before by adding details to the `package.json` file, such as the `start` line in the `scripts` block. I also tried moving the `app.js` file to the root directory, updating the reference in the HTML code, and committing and deploying again.

The build appears as successful in terminal. However, when I click on "Open App" on the Heroku website, the app fails and the logs reveal the below. Have any of you received this error? If so, how did you fix it?

Heroku log:

```
2023-06-25T09:16:43.627247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-06-25T09:16:43.632314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-06-25T09:16:45.545297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-06-25T09:16:46.987365+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-25T09:16:46.987385+00:00 app[web.1]: > herokuapp1@1.0.0 start
2023-06-25T09:16:46.987385+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2023-06-25T09:16:46.987386+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019524+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019526+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019526+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019526+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019526+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019528+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019528+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019528+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019529+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019529+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019529+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-25T09:16:47.019530+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.16.1
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "herokuapp1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "node app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.heroku.com/herokuapp1.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "herokuapp1"
  ],
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing :

```json
"main": "node app.js",
```

to :

```json
"main": "app.js",
```

**Update:**

For people visiting this answer, above + following worked for the user:

Add a procfile like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571078/deployment-to-heroku-error-cannot-find-module-app-server-js).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just tried your suggestion. The same error was produced. (I went through line by line to make sure it was verbatim).

Comment: @auditclause, you can check a few more things. 1. check proper casing of the file names `App.js` vs `app.js`, 2. try to give start script as: `node app/app.js` 3. if your github repository's storing it in some custom path give that e.g. `node /mysrc/src/app/app.js` (based on path of your git repository), 4. see if this helps you (related to procfile): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571078/deployment-to-heroku-error-cannot-find-module-app-server-js)

Comment: Thank you! The info in that link actually worked––I added a procfile and the error is gone. (Interestingly, a new error is popping up but it's regarding the 'window' in the Javascript itself. I'll post that in a different thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Error resolved. Per [subdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584623/subdeveloper)'s ([suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571078/deployment-to-heroku-error-cannot-find-module-app-server-js)), I added a procfile to the root directory. It had one line:

```
web: node app.js
```

The error is no longer appears. (There is a new error popping up, but since it's related to the 'window' in the Javascript code, I'll move that to a new thread.)